# Perl Tk refresh checkbutton inside sub

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have some checkboxes that change their value inside sub. Multiple times. But I all checkboxes stay const until the end of sub. And only when sub finished, checkboxes update. 
So how to make them updating every time their value changes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either want to call `$mainwindow->idletasks` or `$mainwindow->update` inside the subroutine.   `idletasks` only updates the screen, while `update` processes new user interaction (this [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/perl-win32-users@listserv.activestate.com/msg10795.html) explains it better).  Basically, you've got to give MainLoop a chance to catch up with the changes you're making.

Comment: Thank you! But may I somehow update them even without main window methods, every time value changes?